# Quais as vantagens em utilizar o Jenkins para executar processos em background?

Tags: java, batch, jenkins

Estou tendo contato com um sistema web onde utilizam o jenkins para executar processos em background, no caso, queries para gerar relatórios. O usuário faz a solicitação e o processamento é feito pelo jenkins.

Eu já utilizei threads para realizar processamentos desse tipo. A solicitação era feita e quando o processamento terminava o usuário recebia uma notificação via email.

Quais as vantagens de se utilizar o jenkins nesse caso? Existe algum artigo específico para esse tipo de uso? Quais os termos que eu deveria pesquisar?

Answer (score 1):

A única vantagem que eu vejo é que isso fica no controle dos devs para gerar esses relatórios, normalmente são bem pesados para o banco de dados para serem gerados e isso pode derrubar a aplicação se um usuário ficar apertando gerar toda hora ou tentar gerar em um horário de pico da aplicação.